# Can't access Tomcat in NetBeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, java-8

I've a really big problem. I installed the new `NetBeans 8.0` and by the way doing this I also changed my `Tomcat` to `7.0`. Also I set Tomcats `tomcat-users.xml (../Tomcat 7.0/conf/tomcat-users.xml)` manager role and set the name and password in Tomcat options in NetBeans.

If I'm running my project now (which was running perfectly befor, but i unfortunately deleted my old environment befor the new setup) the server start but the project is not deployed on Tomcat.

If I go to `localhost:8080` `Tomcat server` is running. I can access Tomcat with my username and password I specified but if I try to see `Tomcats Web Applications` folder in NetBeans I alway recieve the error message:

> "Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct
>   username and password with the "manager-script" role in Tomcat
>   customizer in the Server Manager."

It is not the first time I set up Netbeans with Tomcat but I never had this problem, if somebody have any idea how to solve this problem I would be really thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the solution. I just had to diable NetBeans proxy settings. I really have no clue how this could trigger the error but finally I'm able to access Tomcat in NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create or update `tomcat-users.xml` in `tomcathome\conf` folder by adding manager role

```
<tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="admin"/>
 <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager"/>
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
 <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. This takes still no effect. The problom still exists. I allready tried all possible varieties.